# Долгая загрузка windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10

По какой то причине замедлилась загрузка windows до запуска пользователя. На чистой винде загрузка была не более 5-10 секунд. Теперь же полная загрузка системы  полторы - 2 минуты. 
Прочекал полифилам что так стало тормозить систему до самой загрузки пользователя, оказалось процесс smss.exe.
Какие могут быть причины и как можно это поправить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[Логи полифила](https://yadi.sk/d/5hu05AFx3HWYnY)

Answer (score 1):

1. Отправить файл на проверку https://www.virustotal.com
2. Создать нового пользователя и проверить как под ним загружаеться.
3. Загрузиться в безопасном режиме и посмотреть лог
4. в диспечере нажмите правой открить файл .  путь должен быть \WINDOWS\system32\smss.exe
5. smss.exe  Процес отвечаєт за завершение сесии пользователя.
6. посмотрите журнал ошибок.
7. попробуйте отключить все установленые программы с автозагрузки.